# Code login C# using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures, authentication

I have stored procedure check_user:

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[check_user]
    @u nvarchar(20),
    @p nvarchar(20)
AS
BEGIN
    declare @count int
    declare @res bit

    select @count = COUNT(*) 
    from Account 
    where username = @u and passwd = @p

    if @count > 0
        set @res = 1
    else 
        set @res = 0

    select @res
end
```

Using that code in Visual Studio, `Demoentities` is name of Entity Framework in connection settings

```
Demoentities dm = new Demoentities();

if(dm.checkuser(tb_user.Text,tb.pass.Text) == 1)
     MessageBox.Show("Login successfully!");
```

But I see error:

> Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectResult' and 'int'

Help me!

Comment: instead of `select @count ...` you can do `select @res ...` and it will save you comparing values

Comment: so what is not working here ?

Comment: Please show the code in `dm.checkuser`

Comment: But wrong?!? What wrong?^^

Comment: that error:   Error 1 Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectResult<bool?>' and 'int'

Comment: Try `if((int)dm.checkuser(tb_user.Text,tb.pass.Text) == 1)`

Comment: Thank @Cataklysim! But it not working!

Answer (score 0):

Well you can't compare two different types. Maybe try to alter your procedure:

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[check_user]
@u nvarchar(20),
@p nvarchar(20)
as
begin
    declare @count int
    declare @result bit
    select @count = COUNT(*) from Account where username = @u and passwd = @p
    if @count > 0
        set @result = 1
    else 
        set @result = 0
    Return @result
end
```

Instead of a `select @res`at the end, try a `return`.

Also, change the `if`statement into:

`if(dm.checkuser(tb_user.Text,tb.pass.Text))
      MessageBox.Show("Login successfully!");`

EDIT: Just got in mind: if your method `dm.checkuser(string, string)`doesn't return a bool, try to edit that too. Don't know the code for that method to check... sry.

Comment: I used your code and I get error: Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool'. Please help me code login using entityframework :(

Comment: My bad. Change the result type in your method to a bool. That should do the trick. As I said, maybe you should post your 'dm.checkuser()' method code for us.

Answer (score 0):

Hello there you have to use Single() function because c# doesn't convert IQuerable type to int

```
if(dm.checkuser(tb_user.Text,tb.pass.Text).single() == 1)
 MessageBox.Show("Login successfully!");
```